# Creating specific timestamp (python3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use current timestamp minus 7 days as a variable in my python code.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

my_timestamp = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)

print(my_timestamp)
```

output: 2022-10-11 14:35:28.946221

wanted output: 2022-10-11 14:35:28.946

I need to use this timestamp in my code as variable and my wanted output is 2022-10-11 14:35:28.946
How can I format timestamp in order to get wanted output?

Comment: What is wrong with the current output, do you not want the last three digits?

Comment: The dirtiest way is to cut off 3 last characters like so: `str(my_timestamp)[:-3]`. But actually you might want your own format using [`datetime.strftime`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: How about this `str(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7))[:-3]`? Anyway, you probably should do formatting through [strftime() and strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: @Karolis S this is working but I need timestamp data type.

Comment: @It_is_Chris yes, I don't not want the last three digits and it needs to be a timestamp.

Comment: @My80 I do not think it is possible as the decimal is microseconds and there is no millisecond attribute to datetime. So 100,000 microseconds would be .1 seconds. Doing `.946` would essentially be the equivalent of `.000946` which is not the same time as `.946221` A datetime object is always going to have a six-digit microsecond.

Comment: @It_is_Chris can I frmat to string and back to timestamp?

Comment: @My80 You can format the string but as soon as you go back to a `datetime.datetime` object the microseconds will always be 6 digits. So depending on how you convert it back to a datetime.datetime object you will either get `.946000` or `.000946`, which are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract out the unwanted microseconds.

```
today = datetime.today()
my_timestamp = today - timedelta(days=7, microseconds=today.microsecond % 1000)
```

This can be a one-liner on Python 3.8+ using an assignment expression.

```
my_timestamp = (t:=datetime.today()) - timedelta(days=7, microseconds=t.microsecond % 1000)
```

To display this without the trailing zeros do

```
print(my_timestamp.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds'))
```

which gives

```
2022-10-11 10:20:15.812
```

An alternative to subtracting out the unwanted microseconds is to replace them (copied from @It_is_Chris's deleted answer):

```
my_timestamp = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
new = my_timestamp.replace(microsecond=int(my_timestamp.microsecond/1000))
```

Comment: this is giving me a str output '2022-10-11T16:26:26.206' and I need timestamp without T in the timestamp. I need 2022-10-11 16:26:26.206

Comment: To get it without the `T` add the argument `sep=' '`. (I have updated my answer with this information.)

Comment: I need data type timestamp. Thank you for your help I will try to use string.

Comment: Do you need a `datetime.datetime` or a `pd.Timestamp`? The first part of my answer shows how to geta a `datetime.datetime` that keeps the milliseconds but drops the microseconds.  You can take the result of that and pass it to `pd.Timestamp()` to get the pandas datatype.

Comment: Ok, I Will they. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want something like that:

```
my_timestamp = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=7)
ms = str(my_timestamp.microsecond)[:3]
```

Comment: I got error with seconds. I tryed this: e = datetime.today()
e = np.round(e.microsecond , 3) but the output is 238889. I need timestamp output example: 2022-10-11 14:35:28.946

Comment: You should subtract the seconds part, not all e.seconds = np.round(e.seconds , 3)

Comment: I need this output 2022-10-11 16:26:26.206 so I need to substract microseconds.

Comment: With seconds is not working.

Comment: Try this:
my_timestamp = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=7)
ms = str(my_timestamp.microsecond)[:3]

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: same error. Thank you for your help I will try to find solution.